# Logout issue in Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: feature-request, logout

After I log out from my account, and close my window, loading the page will log in back with my account. It happens when I am not clearing my history and files. When I use public computers it will create problems.

When I click the login button on Stack Exchange, it will log in me back.

Please change the code so that sessions are really removed.

Comment: What browser? Can't reproduce here with Chrome 16.0.192.63. and are you _sure_ it's actually logging you back in? A page that has previously been downloaded and is accessed via the 'back' button will often just reload the page from said cache, user name and all (which isn't an SE problem.) There's no evil scripting going on to alter the page dynamically after that.

Comment: Sorry, that back button issue could not found now.. I think they already corrected it.. Till last week I have found that issue.. Previously I have faced  it with IE and Fire fox

Answer (score 4):

After you click the "Log out" link from your user drop-down, are you sure you're clicking the "Are you sure?" type button that comes next?

[image]

Comment: Yes, me too. I'm suggesting to really being logged out, I also see for short a Global Logout page, however restarting the browser, clicking login, automatically logs me in without asking for a password, using StackExchange auth.